# "Build deployment package" gone! Azure SDK's fault?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-sdk-.net

The option to "Build deployment package", located between "Clean" and "Publish" in a Web Project's context menu of Visual Studio (I use 2010) has disappeared.

I suspect the Azure SDK or something related behind this as that changes the publication dialog and another machine in my office that hasn't got this installed still has the option.

Does somebody know how to get it back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I manage to get the "Build Deployment Package" back by uninstalling "Microsoft Web Publish" from Control Panel.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. The new web publish thing killed this option. Unless someone tells me how you can have both the new web publish stuff and this option that's the answer.